# Can I use one preposition for two adjectives that take different prepositions? -- "Conscious (about) and critical of.."

Tags: prepositions, word-request, parallelism

> Ironically, people will become more conscious *about*, **and** **probably** **critical** **of**, your informal speech when it comes off as uptight.

1. Can I drop *about*?
2. Is the setting off of the part in bold correct?
3. Does uptight capture *showing* *excessive* *adherence* *to* *rules*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since **conscious...of** is the standard collocation, yes, you could do so:

> ... conscious and probably critical of...

But you cannot do so when the preposition is not licensed by the adjective. For example: *conscious of and delighted with* cannot become *conscious and delighted with* because **conscious with** is an unlicensed combination.

P.S. This "sharing" of a preposition tends to occur in writing more than in conversation. It is not a natural way of speaking, and as a result many native speakers bungle it when they write, using unlicensed combinations. I am not an advocate for its use by any means. I would prefer to economize by using a pronoun instead of sharing a preposition:

> People will become more conscious of your informal speech and probably critical
>   of **it**...

Comment: I thought conscious about was the correct combination. Thank you.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=conscious+of%2Cconscious+about&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cconscious%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconscious%20about%3B%2Cc0

Comment: But **self-conscious about**...

Comment: related: is it normal to use em-dashes, commands or nothing at all for combos like "conscious of and delighted with"? "conscious of -- and delighted with -- the whatsit" "conscious of, and delighted with, the whatsit"... can't find this anywhere

Comment: @Rhubarb: em-dashes would be perfectly acceptable, or commas, treating the second phrase as an aside: *"I'm aware of—and delighted with—the plan that is underway to turn this patch of green space into a parking lot," said the mayor.*